# is there any function can convert array with objects into associative array with key of object pick by defined in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, object

like the following function `array_object_key_picker`

```
$a = [
    ["name" => "John", "gender" => "man"],
    ["name" => "Alex", "gender" => "man"],
    ["name" => "Luxy", "gender" => "woman"],
];

$b = array_object_key_picker($a, "name");

// var_dump($b) =>
[
    "John" => ["name" => "John", "gender" => "man"],
    "Alex" => ["name" => "Alex", "gender" => "man"],
    "Luxy" => ["name" => "Luxy", "gender" => "woman"],
]
```

Comment: `$a` doesn't contain any objects. It's simply a multi dimensional array.

Comment: Now some friendly people have given you the answer, but as a future reference, you actually need to make an attempt to solve the issue yourself first. Questions like this (basically _"code this for me"_) are always at risk of getting down voted + closed if it doesn't contain any attempts at all. SO isn't a free coding service.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a couple of array methods to achieve the result ( although as pointed out - there are no objects involved).

```
$a = [
        ["name" => "John", "gender" => "man"],
        ["name" => "Alex", "gender" => "man"],
        ["name" => "Luxy", "gender" => "woman"],
];

$b = array_combine(array_column($a, "name"), $a);

print_r($b);
```

gives...

```
Array
(
    [John] => Array
        (
            [name] => John
            [gender] => man
        )

    [Alex] => Array
        (
            [name] => Alex
            [gender] => man
        )

    [Luxy] => Array
        (
            [name] => Luxy
            [gender] => woman
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do this is probably to use `array_column` passing *null* as the second parameter. [From the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php):

> It may also be NULL to return complete arrays or objects (this is useful together with index_key to reindex the array).

So you just need to use:

```
$b = array_column($a, null, 'name');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your array does not contain any objects. If you happen to have objects inside your array, you can convert them to array using the `(array)` cast.

---

To get, what your requested result looks like, you can iterate over the array using a foreach loop:

```
$newArray = [];
$a = [
    ["name" => "John", "gender" => "man"],
    ["name" => "Alex", "gender" => "man"],
    ["name" => "Luxy", "gender" => "woman"],
];

foreach ($a as $element) {
    $newArray[$element['name']] = $element;
}

print_r($newArray); // Prints your desired result
```

Comment: Yeah sure, he would have to do it on all elements inside the array. Even tho that would not even yield the requested result.

Comment: You are right, its `(array)` not `(object)`, my bad. Its to early in the morning :P